# Open SP.UI.ModalDialog within another ModalDialog

Tags: modal-dialog

Can I open SP.UI.ModalDialog within another ModalDialog?

I mean, I can, and opening works fine. What does not work, is closing second dialog. Neither default buttons for maximizing and closing window (in dialog's top bar) do anything, nor custom button with `SP.UI.ModalDialog.close` method.

Is it possible to successfully open **and close** a ModalDialog within ModalDialog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution to this problem:

First dialog had `asp:Button`, that would open second dialog. The JS method for this was in `OnClientClick`. What I noticed, was that button click would reload first page again.

I changed `asp:Button` to HTML button: `<input type="button" onclick="OpenSubDialog('/_layouts/SecondForm.aspx')">`. Also in second dialog, save/close button now calls JS to close from code-behind:

```
 HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
 context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup()</script>");
 context.Response.Flush();
 context.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. I have an example here that worked for me at least some time ago:

Function to open the first dialog:

```
function openRegAtt() {SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(regAttOptions);}
```

JS inside the first dialog page:

```
function openAddPpl() {SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(addPplOptions);}
```

Nothing special about it tbh, hard to say why it shouldn't work.

Comment: This is exactly how I open the dialog. But then I cannot close it.